# Deveríamos reportar os bugs ou problemas de tradução em Inglês?

Tags: debate, tradução, proposta-para-faq

Talvez eu esteja errado, mas pelo o que eu sei os bugs aqui no site devem ser reportados aqui no Meta com a tag [bug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) e caso relacionado a tradução com a adição da tag [tradução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o), o problema é que ao fazer uma pesquisa pela quantidade de perguntas com a tag [bug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) ([link pesquisa](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=newest&pagesize=50)) e comparando com a quantidade de perguntas com a tag [status-pronto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-pronto), você nota que quase nada foi resolvido.

Observando isso eu acabo chegando à conclusão que o sistema de reportar bugs funciona da seguinte forma: um usuário posta o bug e @Gabe traduz e repassa para os desenvolvedores do site arrumarem.

### Ideia:

Se o sistema funciona dessa forma (que está bem lenta), acho então que deveríamos mudar o jeito como reportamos os bugs, talvez se os relatórios de bug estivesse escrito em Inglês os desenvolvedores teriam acesso a eles diretamente, pois não haveria necessidade de tradução e assim eles poderiam resolver o problema, mais rapidamente.

### Sugestão sobre o formato do relatório de bug: (caso a ideia acima seja aceita)

Para não infringir o segundo objetivo mais importante do site que é ser em Português o formato do relatório seria apenas um pouco diferente:

- O título seria em Inglês seguido por sua tradução em Português entre parenteses (caso ainda haja caracteres disponíveis);
- O corpo do relatório seria composto de uma primeira parte em Inglês e em seguida sua tradução em Português;
- Caso o usuário, não escreva muito bem em Inglês ele poderia postar o relatório em Português e outro membro da comunidade adicionaria uma tradução no mesmo post.

Answer (score 4):

Tive a mesma sensação quanto à discussão do "pt" ou "br", tanto que aqui parecia encerrado o assunto, mas no mesmo dia em que a questão foi levantada no "metão", foi decidido que seria pt finalmente.

Talvez essa coisa de traduzir sobrecarregue o Gabe, então melhor irmos ao inglês diretamente.

Paralelamente, saiu a questão de reportar lá ou aqui os bugs, e a proposta de usarmos inglês é compatível com a resposta que eu propus lá. vejam as duas questões nos links a seguir para acompanhar a conversa:

[Foreign language meta questions shouldn't be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214277/foreign-language-meta-questions-shouldnt-be-migrated/)

[Is “stackoverflow em Português” for Brazilians only?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214167/is-stackoverflow-em-portugues-for-brazilians-only/)

Respondendo ao comment do Zignd: Concordo com a idéia de 2 línguas. Eu acho que temos que postar em inglês quando se tratar de assuntos que envolvam a equipe do SE, enquanto o time dos representantes que falam português for escasso. De qualquer forma, acho importante que esteja postado em inglês mas com tradução pt, para que todos participem. Não dá pra confiar em ferramentas automáticas.

Quanto a postar no "metão", o 1o link que eu postei tem minha opinião contra na resposta.
Em resumo: sou contra decisões sobre o pt.SO que não incluam a nossa comunidade toda. Nós temos que debater e ajudar a decidir, e transmitir nossa opinião corretamente à equipe do SE.

Foi assim que conseguimos o pt.SO no lugar de br.SO. Discussão na nossa comunidade, debate na nossa comunidade, devidamente reportada para a equipe do SE.

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi direito, você é a favor da minha proposta então?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que ter dois idiomas aqui no meta pode ficar confuso. Se é para reportar bugs em inglês, melhor postar direto no metão.

Porém, vejo dois problemas na sua proposta:

- Não dá para decidirmos isso sozinhos, sem opinião do Gabe e/ou outros da equipe da SE
- Como o site foi lançado bem próximo ao fim do ano, ao menos parte da lentidão deve ser devida a férias dos desenvolvedores (e, acredito, do próprio Gabe).

Portanto, melhor aguardar mais uma ou duas semanas para ver se a coisa engrena. Se o site for bem, acho que a SE pode acabar contratando mais gente que fala português para conseguir dar conta do recado. Os moderadores, que ainda não temos, também poderão ajudar.

#### Por outro lado...

Eu sinto falta de podermos ouvir a opinião de certos moderadores, desenvolvedores e gerentes de comunidade aqui. Mas eles só poderiam se expressar em inglês, então fico dividido, pois acho mesmo que ter dois idiomas seria uma confusão. Talvez devêssemos abrir uma ou outra exceção e ter conteúdo em inglês + tradução, porém acho que não é o caso de fazer isso para bugs. O feedback sobre bugs geralmente é bem curto, e em muitos casos bastaria quem consertou entrar e colocar a tag de status-pronto.

Comment: Você não acha melhor manter as coisas relacionadas SOPT apenas aqui no Meta do SOPT? Ficaria muito mais fácil encontrar os relatórios de bugs aqui do que em outro site, que por sinal é imenso como o Metão. Talvez deixar os relatórios aqui em Inglês mesmo sem duplo idioma no post. Mas como você disse é melhor esperar uma resposta do @Gabe.

Comment: @Zignd Minha resposta não estava muito clara, editei. Eu mesmo fico dividido. De todo modo é melhor mesmo darmos mais tempo ao site para decidirmos isso.

Comment: Eu quero lembrar que mesmo a pessoa inicialmente não postando nas duas linguas, com uma certa facilidade qualquer um de nós pode acrescentar uma boa tradução. Volta e meia faço isso com respostas postadas parcialmente em inglês (quando se trata de citação de documentação original por exemplo).

Comment: Não acho que seja o caso de precisar de várias pessoas para dar conta. A comunidade pode se gerir sozinha em quase tudo. Só precisa ter uma ponte da comunidade com a equipe para alguns poucos assuntos que a comunidade não pode resolver sozinha. Inclusive quando se iniciou vários sites em inglês só tinha 1 pessoa dedicada a cuidar da comunidade. Só passou ter outras quando teve dezenas de sites. Embora isso seja algo que eles que se resolvam internamente :) O que precisamos é de um solução para a situação atual. Eu não me importo de misturar línguas, se ajudar o andamento.

Comment: Votei contra porque acho que está claro que precisamos usar as duas línguas para fazer as coisas andarem. Em chat o Shog9 já disse que não é problema. Problemas específicos nossos **podem** ser colocados **também** em inglês. Problemas gerais da rede, vão para o metão (atualmente MSO mas que mudará p/ o MSE) só em inglês. Se alguém postar um problema em português aqui, seria útil incentivar a pessoa postar no metão ou alguém fazer para ela. Deixar nosso meta para nossos problemas.

Comment: É @bigown, pelo visto é o jeito de aumentar a visibilidade aqui no meta. Pensei em criar uma tag `english-content` ou `english-version`, ou `english-available`, o que acha? Assim o pessoal poderia seguir essa tag.

Comment: É meta-tag, né? Em geral não gosto, mas é o... meta, né? :) Facilitaria para eles monitorarem. Podemos testar e ver o que eles acham. O teste não fará mal. Eu acabei esquecendo de completar a frase no comentário acima. Se o problema for geral da rede, e for colocado aqui, seria útil colocar no metão também.